# Why does this variable in my summary output not show up with a 1 or a 2?

Tags: r, regression, linear-regression, summary

[Variable Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xfCwR.png)

[Summary Output of what is confusing me.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/czCLs.png)

[Summary Output that made sense to me before!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0xBsh.png)

If you notice, one of the summary outputs has a (2.0) to represent which one is bringing/raising the model if included whereas the other, has no such thing and I assume is just saying that it goes down/up when there are simply eyes being used PERIOD when I more-so care about HOW MANY are being used.

Thank You!

Comment: In the first model, `Eyes Open` is being treated as a continuous variable. In the second, it's being treated as a factor with two levels.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. As suggested here in the comments <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66558061/why-does-my-r-summary-not-specify-a-1-or-a-2> please read through this: <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example> and then edit your first question. It makes no sense to as multiple times the same question with different format. This will provide adequate support.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does my R summary not specify a 1 or a 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66558061/why-does-my-r-summary-not-specify-a-1-or-a-2)